# subdomain on route53 private hosted Zone

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I have been trying to setup a Private Hosted Zone in **route53** with current associated VPCs in eu-west-1 and will soon add more. I have conformed that my VPC has DNS resolution option set to yes and necessary DHCP option sets are also created. I have added a DNS record under the domain.local domain and it works fine. However, the issue comes when I tried to created a sub-damain dev.domain.local and tried to associate with the same VPC.  I see the following error
*"A conflicting domain is already associated with the given VPC or Delegation Set."*

My intention is to have one parent private zone as zorotools.local and several subdomain such as dev.domain.local, staging.domain.local, prod.domain.local etc.

I would then associate ec2 instances with these DNS names.

So, please let me know what mistake I am making and how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Just create records with the remainder of the FQDN filled out. So in this case create "server1.dev" and it will resolve to "server1.dev.domain.local".